# how to add soap header to react-native?

Tags: c#, react-native

*I use soap header in c# like this :*

```
MeyerWebService.WebServiceEmployees tasnifWS = new MeyerWebService.WebServiceEmployees();
        tasnifWS.UserDetailsValue = new UserDetails()
        {
            userName = "**",
            password = "**"
        };
```

But I dont know how to do this in react-native

Comment: Have you tried using https://github.com/adamski/react-native-soap-request ? https://www.google.com/search?q=soap+call+from+react+native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple module for making SOAP requests with WSSecurity

```
npm install react-native-soap-request --save
```

Example

```
const soapRequest = new SoapRequest({
  security: {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
  },
  targetNamespace: 'http://soap.acme.com/2.0/soap-access-services',
  commonTypes: 'http://soap.acme.com/2.0/soap-common-types',
  requestURL: soapWebserviceURL
});

const xmlRequest = soapRequest.createRequest({
  'soap:ProductRegistrationRequest': {
    attributes: {
      'xmlns:soap': 'http://soap.acme.com/2.0/soap-access-services',
      'xmlns:cmn': 'http://soap.acme.com/2.0/soap-common-types'
    },
    'soap:productId': {
      'cmn:internalId': {
        'cmn:id': productId
      }
    },
    'soap:userId': {
      'cmn:internalId': {
        'cmn:id': userId
      }
    }
  }
});

const response = await soapRequest.sendRequest();
```